# Which files are need from Kendo core to use Mobile and Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have seen similar questions to this, but I haven't been able to find an answer. Anyway, I am experimenting using Kendo (open source core for now) in a Visual Studio Cordova project. Taking Cordova out of the equation to start with, I am just trying to get a very simple view with the following to work..

```
...
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/angularjs/angular.js"></script>         
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.core.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.mobile.loader.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.mobile.view.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.mobile.pane.js"></script>     
 <script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.mobile.application.js"</script>    

</head>
<body kendo-mobile-application ng-app="foo">
<kendo-mobile-view ng-controller="MyCtrl" k-title="'My Title'" k-layout="'default'">
    <kendo-mobile-header>
        <kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
            <kendo-view-title></kendo-view-title>
        </kendo-mobile-nav-bar>
    </kendo-mobile-header>

    <div>{{hello}}</div>
</kendo-mobile-view>

<script>
    angular.module("foo", [ "kendo.directives" ])
        .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.hello = "Hello World!";
        });
   </script>

   <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I added each Kendo file to try and get rid of each error (initially just started with kendo.core.js)

At this stage, when I try to  run this (just opening index.html in Chrome, out side of Visual Studio), I get

```
 Uncaught TypeError: kendo.ViewContainer is not a function
   Observable.extend.init   @   kendo.mobile.view.js:469
   Widget.extend.init   @   kendo.mobile.pane.js:102
   startHistory @   kendo.mobile.application.js:171
```

So this is occuring at the line

```
     that.viewContainer = new kendo.ViewContainer(that.container);
```

in the file `kendo.mobile.view.js`.

I don't seem to be able to find where `ViewContainer` is declared.
If I use a CDN of like `<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.930/js/kendo.all.min.js">` then this works fine, so I need to know which references to use from the core library.

Comment: So why don't you just use the `Kendo.mobile.min.js` file instead of listing all the files individually.

Comment: I used bower to get kendo ui core, and the file `Kendo.mobile.min.js` does not exist in the distribution. It appears to just have all the individuals (both full and minified), so need to know which I need to include, and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

I found the doco that explains what I need [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/supporting/scripts-hybridui).

I added everything for the "Application" section (in the exact order listed), and then put

```
<script src="lib/kendo-ui-core/src/js/kendo.angular.js"></script>
```

at the end.